# Script to copy Egde-Chromium browsing history from a remote machine. Try-catch, custom object building

Tags: powershell

There are some Kiosk machines for people to take a survey. The survey is running by a 3rd party, so no way to get the data from them. To measure how much machines are in use I wrote a script to pull Edge-Chromium browsing history from a remote machine

````
function Copy-FileRemotely
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )
    
    try
    {       
        $isSuccess = $true
        $Message = Copy-Item -Path "\\$ComputerName\c$\Users\SMZSurvey2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\History" -Destination $PSScriptRoot\$ComputerName -Force -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru
    }
    catch
    {
        $isSuccess = $false
        $Message = ($_.Exception).Message
    }
    return [pscustomobject]@{
        'ComputerName'   = $ComputerName
        'isSuccess'      = $isSuccess
        'Message'        = $Message
        
    }
    
}

$comps = "smz-F9246-DB", "xxx"
$result = @()
foreach ($comp in $comps)
{
    $result += Copy-FileRemotely $comp
}
$result | Out-GridView
sleep 10
```
````

Comment: just for my curiosity ... how does the cache give you "how much machines are in use"?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The history file contains titles of pages a user visited, the datestamps, etc. When a person finishes a survey, Edge displays him the "Thank you!" page. I guess I count those pages per day. It gives me the number of people that took a survey test on a particular machine.

Comment: ah! thank you for the "why" of it. [*grin*] ///// i would likely use `Invoke-Command` to run your code on each system in parallel and let the count be sent back to you instead of the whole list of pages. i suspect that could get QUITE large ... and make things rather slow when sent across the network.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Edge-Chromium keeps its browsing history data in SQLite database which stored in a file called History. I don't know how to decipher the file with Invoke-Command.

Comment: ah! i presumed you had code that you were running to decipher that info. if you DO have something that you can run on the _target_ systems, then i would do that. less to shove across your network AND running the code in parallel makes it seem worth your while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make what you have more readable, I would not create a helper function to replace `Copy-Item`:

```sh
$comps = "smz-F9246-DB", "xxx"

$result = foreach ($comp in $comps) {
  Try { Copy-Item `
    -Path "\\$comp\c$\Users\SMZSurvey2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\History" `
    -Destination "$PSScriptRoot\$ComputerName" -Force -PassThru
  }
  Catch [Common.Exceptions.You.See] { Write-Output "$comp could not be contacted, skipping..." }
}

# output list of files/failures
$result
```

Based on your comments, you just want the count of visits to a specific site, which is pretty straightforward if you have powershell remoting available. I adapted [this code](https://github.com/rvrsh3ll/Misc-Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/Get-BrowserData.ps1) by user rvrsh3ll, which pulls website names from the chromium `History` file.

```
# Connect to each machine and get the browsing history
$result = Foreach ($comp in $comps) {

  Try { 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -EA Stop -ScriptBlock {

    # Regex returns trimmed URL
    $Regex = '(http(|s))://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?'
    $Site = 'https://stackoverflow.com'  # Set this

    # Seach chrome history for site visits
    $Count = (
      Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\SMZSurvey2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\History" -EA Stop|
      Select-String -AllMatches $regex |
      % {($_.Matches).Value} | 
      Where {$_ -like $Site}
    ).Count

    # output as object
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      ComputerName = $using:comp
      SiteVisits   = $Count
      Success      = ($Count -gt -1) -and ($null -ne $Count)
    }
  } 
  } Catch {[PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName=$comp;SiteVisits='N/A';Success=$false}}
}

# Output results:
$result | FT ComputerName,SiteVisits,Success
```

And the results look like so:

```
ComputerName SiteVisits Success
------------ ---------- -------
offline-PC   N/A          False
in-use-PC    2             True
unused-PC    0             True
```

Hopefully this helps you skip the step of processing the file.